# iOS 16.4.1 mobile App reports error Failed host lookup:'storage.googleapis.com'

Tags: api, storage

One of my App User in country Malawi is reporting an error when my App tries to connect to storage.googleapis.com. The error message is Failed host lookup:'storage.googleapis.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided , or not known, errno=8)

Wanted to understand if the API is restricted somehow for users of that country, or what could be the reasons for this error. The App is generally working fine for users from other countries.

The App was built as a Flutter iOS App.

Asked the user to try and download the files by providing the full URL in the browser and it is able to download. But from the App it fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.